# Error duplicate entry en la ejecución

Tags: android, android-studio, qr

Tengo el siguiente error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     com/google/zxing/aztec/AztecDetectorResult.class

¿Cuál puede ser la causa de este error?

Este es mi gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "corpoeurekait.epaycomercios"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support',
        module: 'support-annotations'


    })


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'androidmads.library.qrgenearator:QRGenearator:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Revisa esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39388746/4092887) e investiga mas sobre este error buscando `java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry` en Google. Si solucionas tu problema, por favor publica y acepta tu propia respuesta. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Solucione el problema eliminando lo siguiente:

como estaba:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'androidmads.library.qrgenearator:QRGenearator:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
```

como quedo:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
```

Comment: Eliminar es facil para evitar duplicados, pero eliminaste 'androidmads.library.qrgenearator:QRGenearator:1.0.2' ¿No lo necesitas?

Comment: Las librerias que usa son similares a la que usa el 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8', por eso es que me daba error de duplicado, al eliminarla la app se ejecuta sin problema.

Comment: QRGenerator es para salvar codigos QR como imagen y para leerlos mediante xZing,  mientras que xZing es para leer códigos. Si no deseas guardar como imagen el código puedes usar solo xzing